# Android SQLite database importing records

Tags: android, database, sqlite

What is the best way to get aproxmatly 1900 records into a SQLite database when the app is first run?

1. Importing from text file
2. Importing from code
3. Downloading from the web
4. Packaging the database with the app.

Currently I important from a text file but this takes a couple of minutes to parse the xml first.

Thanks.

Comment: While this is an important issue to address in many apps, I don't think your question is a good fit for the format here at Stack Overflow. The answer depends on other details of your app. Can your app function without the data or with a partial set of the data? If so, then maybe you can create a service that spawns a thread to do the download without impacting the UX for your app. Can you serve the data from a REST API or GraphQL server or something similar? This will help reduce the size of the downloaded APK if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to you to download from a webservice or Restful API.

Add the request into the onCreate() and onUpgrade() of your SQLiteOpenHelper to download it on every upgrade of the database if you are going to add/modify/delete any table of your DB.

Regards